# Where is the body of function in header files of C

Tags: c, function, header-files

When i look at header files files of C(or C++)
**for example** 
stdio.h
there are definition of some functions
**for example**

```
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fopen (const char*, const char*);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW freopen (const char*, const char*, FILE*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fflush (FILE*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fclose (FILE*);
/* MS puts remove & rename (but not wide versions) in io.h  also */
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW remove (const char*);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW rename (const char*, const char*);
_CRTIMP FILE* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW tmpfile (void);
_CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW tmpnam (char*);
```

Can you tell me
where are the body of theese functions.....

Comment: You do not even have to open any files on your system. Sometimes they are posted on the web as html files like this https://docs.google.com/viewer?pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxyeWFuYnJvb21maWVsZHxneDo1MmVlMGE3ZWY0M2U4ODk3&docid=ceac0a02f360520a8550d5bb6203700d%7C434bbc224d60a89bc0bbca61eea5d16d&chan=EQAAACOxrV%2B9nw4spSLems6Hb5e7CThUhkFvzhJxKF5%2BcOXC&a=v&rel=zip;z428;io.h or this https://svn.janelia.org/penglab/projects/vaa3d/trunk/v3d_main/common_lib/mingw32/include/stdio.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, as @Daren Thomas said, you'll have .c file matching the hader (.h file). However, regarding the standard library, these c files come precompiled and put together in a big file (for example, libc.so), and can be found in the lib folder of your compiler in Windows, and in the /usr/lib folder in Unix/Linus OS's.

For g++, the libc library is used as the standard library. You can download the package from here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.9.tar.gz

... and browse the source code for all functions.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the body is in a file with the same name, but ending in `.c` or `.cpp`.

Sometimes you don't have the source code, so look for `.o`, which contains the object code for your library, i.e. the compiled library. The header file is then a kind of API description.

In special cases like `stdio.h`, which are part of the standard library, the location of these files are implementation specific. In fact, the existence of these files are implementation specific too - I believe a compiler may choose to provide this information however it pleases to do so.

Comment: but there is not a file with name 
stdio.c or 
stdio.cpp or 
stdio.o

Comment: @namco: because the implementation is in the runtime libaries. For MS, the libraries are these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: And for linux, a lot of the header files provide prototypes for system calls, which aren't implemented in C at all are are basically inline assembly or kernel level code

Comment: @namco Also, the compiler manufacturer usually isn't too happy to give away his whole source code/livelihood for free. Nowadays some do however, as their profit isn't related to the implementation of the standard libraries. And then of course there is always open-source GCC, which is free.